# How to avoid bloating the controller code in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, coding-style, controllers

Controllers are there in MVC pattern to process user input and output. So, input validation and response preparation should be done in a controller.

For instance, I have a controller method "save" which:

- looks for input data
- runs a validator on the data
- if inputs are valid, loads an appropriate model, sets its fields to input values, and calls its `save()` method
- if inputs are invalid, prepares data to re-load the edit form, shows the form

All this sequence creates quite a mess of linear code. I'd like to separate it somehow. Do I move the validation part to a model? Sounds wrong? Do I create a special "library" class to handle inputs?

In Asp.Net MVC this would be better as they have implemented the "object binder" pattern. Hence, the validation and model field binding goes away and controller gets much lighter. Is there something similar for CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 2):

It is not widely accepted that controllers do validation, I do them in model as per "keep your models fat, controllers thin and views dumb".

It depends on the business logic what is a valid phone number and so on, so it only makes sense for me to have it in model.

Comment: This sounds a valid point. I will just have to adopt to the idea that the model class may be in an 'invalid' state - I've always tried to construct one only when I know it is a 'legal object'.

Comment: @naivists, the controller could check if there was any input at all and save the hassle of loading model (and initializing database) if there wasn't. But any actual validation is really dependent on the domain/business logic which is why, for me, it makes sense to have it in model. There is no consensus for this though, so you need to suit yourself. :)

Comment: Tried moving "input extraction" and validation to the model class. Looks quite good, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would do exactly as you have eluded to and put as much logic into your models as possible. Controllers really should, imo, be used for initiating services and preparing data for views.

You should as much code reusable, ie validators, filters etc..